# Array get's overwritten by while loop, all of them have the same data

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have a text file that contains tv programs. The first column is the name of the channel the second is the time when it starts and the third is the title. I want to break down my text file with a while loop, but when I'm checking outside the loop all the data in the arrays gets overwritten by the last one. Please someone help me :(

```
int i = 0;
FILE *f;
f = fopen("tvmusor.txt", "r");
if (!f)
{
    printf("error", f);
    getchar();
    return -1;
}
char *buf = (char *)malloc(100);
char **chan = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 300);
char **time = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 300);
char **prog = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 300);
for (i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    chan[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
    time[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
    prog[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
}
i = 0;
while (!feof(f))
{
    memset(buf, 0, 100);

    if (fgets(buf, 100, f) == NULL)
        continue;

    if (strlen(buf) > 0 && strchr(buf, '\t') != NULL)
    {
        chan[i] = strtok(buf, "\t");
        time[i] = strtok(0, "\t");
        prog[i] = strtok(0, "\n");
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", chan[i], time[i], prog[i]);
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how the input text file looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the pointer instead of copying the contents.

1. `strtok` returns the pointer to the location of token found in the `buf`.

   Hence `chan[i]` , `time[i]` and `prog[i]` pointers will be pointing to latest contents of `buf` when you come out of the loop.
2. Also you have `memory` leaks when you overwrite `chan[i]` , `time[i]` and `prog[i]` with `strok`.

Thus change this

```
    chan[i] = strtok(buf, "\t");
    time[i] = strtok(0, "\t");
    prog[i] = strtok(0, "\n");
```

to

```
    strncpy(chan[i], strtok(buf, "\t"), 30);
    strncpy(time[i], strtok(0, "\t"), 30);
    strncpy(prog[i], strtok(0, "\n"), 30);
```

---

> **Warning**: from [strncpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the
>   string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

Comment: You sir, are a legend! Thanks :D